# 'VoiceState' object has no attribute 'voice_channel'

Tags: discord.py

```
@client.command(pass_context=True)
async def join(ctx):
    channel = ctx.message.author.voice.voice_channel
    await client.join_voice_channel(channel)
```

In this command when i run it and type join it doesn't join voice channel, it says 'VoiceState' object has no attribute 'voice_channel'

Answer (score -1):

```py
client.command()
async def join(ctx):
    channel = ctx.author.voice.channel
    await channel.connect()
```